# Expand Log[1+x^2] for x>>1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find a simple form of Log[1+x^2] for x>>1,

but i can't find any useful log(a+b) identity to expand with and then take a limit to cancel a few terms.

How could I expand/simplify Log[1+x^2] for x>>1  in something close to a line?
[image: Log]

In order to explain something like this: 
[image: This]

Comment: the 1 becomes insignificant so you can have 2logx ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @Just_a_fool's comment, you can get additional terms in your approximation.

$$\log\left(1+x^2\right)=\log(x^2)+\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=2\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+O_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right).$$

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: haha yeah duh! Thanks!